# Resharper add well-known types to import type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

Resharper has a very useful feature - import type even if dll is not added. For example i'm typing `var obj = new Graphics()` , R# suggests `Reference System.Drawing and use System.Drawing.Graphics`. But it works with few preconfigured namespaces only.

I'm creating a lot of project that uses some extra libs, for example `System.Net.Http` or `System.Management`. I'm looking for a solution: how can I add these namespace to source where R# is looking for a reference resolution? I googled it but found nothing.

Comment: I think there is only a small set of assemblies that is supported to be added on demand (Add reference in quick fix menu).